# SELECT query leaving out a column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select a table in Oracle redacting one column.  This is the query that I tried, but Oracle does not like it.

```
SELECT (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM USER_TAB_COLS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'LMNOP_USERS'
        AND COLUMN_NAME != 'USER_SECRET' )
FROM LMNOP_USERS;
```

FYI, the subquery does return the list of column names.  Is there a way to write this query other than listing out all the columns?

Comment: No, there's not. List all the columns.

Comment: Correct.  You cannot dynamically select a column in Oracle (or any other database for that matter).  If you really want to do this, you need to put the query into a string and execute the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME||', '
FROM USER_TAB_COLS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'LMNOP_USERS'
    AND COLUMN_NAME != 'USER_SECRET';
```

Then take the list of columns and put them after the `select`.  Remember to delete the last comma.  This saves typing.

You can use `listagg()` to put all the columns on one line, if you prefer.

Comment: Nice. but an additional note to the user :: in `Oracle 11g` it is `listagg`, it is `wm_concat` in 10g. Also, it fails when the concatenated string goes greater than 4000 characters in length. The remaining text simply gets truncated.